# Unknown file system: grub rescue

Tags: boot

I have a Lenovo Y560 laptop on which I installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 as dual boot. Due to some reason I had to recover the boot loader using `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` and `bootrec.exe /fix boot`. It created one partition of size 198 MB named "tet" and both Ubuntu and Windows were working fine.

Yesterday while making some changes in the partition table I deleted that "tets" partition and after reboot I'm getting the following error

```
Error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
```

I tried to boot from the Windows installer CD, but it get stuck at "Starting Windows", so I am not able to run the commands I have mentioned earlier and when I tried to boot from Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot), it got stuck at this error:

```
Memory full
Can't kill any more process.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should try reinstalling GRUB with Boot-Repair.

1. Make a new Ubuntu Live CD and Boot from it.
2. Install `boot-repair` using these commands:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`

   `boot-repair`

[image]

Click "Recommended repair". This will reinstall GRUB in the adequate disk(s). Then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You have deleted partition containing grub and windows 7 boot manager. I am afraid there is no other way except repair the mbr. If ubuntu boot was successful try with "boot-repair" tool ([See here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)) or use windows 7 disk.

Answer (score 0):

Burn a [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/), then boot from it, choose to scan for operationg systems, start Ubuntu and log in. Then execute the command `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where X stands for a letter you can look up with `sudo fdisk -l` or in the disk utility - you need to find the Hard Disk from which you boot and then you'll see something like "Device Name: /dev/sda2" (The number at the end has no importance for this).